# Failed to resolve module specifier when trying to import any module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, import

Everytime I try to import a module I get this error `Failed to resolve module specifier "mongodb". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` and I cant seem to find the answer anywhere. Im just trying to import mongodb `import { mongoClient } from "mongodb";`. Is there any solution to this?

I tried doing what the error says or tried using require keyword but nothing works. I cant use any module

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, I was having the same exact problem and I was just trying to run this all from JS files getting loaded into a static html page.  Needed to setup an Express.JS server run with NodeJS and managed by PM2 that creates the connection and makes all the calls when certain endpoints are reached.